# Why does Update Manager install the i386 version of Skype on an AMD64 system?

Tags: 64-bit, skype, multiarch

Update manager just updated the skype-bin package. I was surprised to see that it is an i386 version and not the 64 bit version given that Skype is now multiarch.

Can someone explain why?

Does an AMD64 system still contain i386 packages?

Answer (score 2):

Skype for Linux is not available as a 64bit native binary package. Why? [Ask Microsoft](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/bd-p/Linux)

So, to install Skype in 64bit Ubuntu you will need some packages from the 32bit architecture.

Microsoft now calls it (for 12.04+ Ubuntu versions) [Skype(multiarch)](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12120/getting-started-with-skype-for-linux#2.1).

Comment: Which packages? It had to install skype-bin first, before I installed skype (dependency issue I guess).